# Java ISBN Creation - String Input Issue

Tags: java, string, char

It's currently incomplete, but I have an issue I'm trying to figure out. I'm creating a program that does the following: 1) Have the user input C (capitalized or lowercase), or R. C has the user input 10 characters, and R randomly generates an ISBN. 2) (and this is where I begin having trouble), the user enters their own ISBN, and the program must check whether or not it is correctly entered. There must be no letters entered, and it must be the exact amount of numbers for it to work as intended.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to go from here. Here's my current code:

```
package lab04;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       String isbn;
       String d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10;
       String c, C;

       System.out.println("Enter 'C' for console output of an ISBN, or 'R'" 
               + "for random output of an ISBN: ");
       char isbn1 = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
       char random;

       if (isbn1 != 'C' && isbn1 != 'c' && isbn1 != 'r' && isbn1 != 'R') {
           System.out.println("Incorrect run type");
           System.exit(1);
        }

       if (isbn1 == 'C' || isbn1 == 'c') {            
          System.out.println("Enter the first 9 digits of an ISBN: ");
          String ch = input.nextLine();

        else if ()
        }
        else {
          if (isbn1 == 'r' || isbn1 == 'R');
          System.out.println("Random generated ISBN-10 is ");
          System.out.print((int)(Math.random() * 123456));
          System.out.print((int)(Math.random() * 1234567));
          System.out.printf("\n\u03C0 = " + 1.0 * Math.PI + "\n");
          System.exit(0);

        }


        }
    }
```

Edit: Here are two examples:

Enter 'C' for console output of an ISBN, or 'R' for random output of an ISBN: 
C
Enter the first 9 digits of an ISBN:

```
123456789
```

Console generated ISBN-10 is `123456789X`

Enter 'C' for console output of an ISBN, or 'R' for random output of an ISBN: 
C
Enter the first 9 digits of an ISBN:

```
1111X1111
```

You need to enter a numeric digit at position `5`

Java Result: `3`

Updated Question: Where would I begin for the ISBN user input to work as it does above? I'm quite stumped.

---

All Entries From Paper:

Run with incorrect entries:
Enter 'C' for console output of an ISBN, or 'R' for random output of an ISBN:

D

Incorrect run type
Java Result: 1

---

Enter 'C' for console output of an ISBN, or 'R' for random output of an ISBN:

c

Enter the first 9 digits of an ISBN:

0123456789

You need to enter exactly 9 digits
Java Result: 2

---

Enter 'C' for console output of an ISBN, or 'R' for random output of an ISBN:

C

Enter the first 9 digits of an ISBN:

1111X1111

You need to enter a numeric digit at position 5
Java Result: 3

---

Run with correct entries:

Enter 'C' for console output of an ISBN, or 'R' for random output of an ISBN:

C

Enter the first 9 digits of an ISBN:

123456789

Console generated ISBN-10 is 123456789X

π = 3.14

---

Enter 'C' for console output of an ISBN, or 'R' for random output of an ISBN:

r

Random generated ISBN-10 is

1391521161

π = 3.14

---

Enter 'C' for console output of an ISBN, or 'R' for random output of an ISBN:

R

Random generated ISBN-10 is

1791839436

π = 3.14

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please put an example of `ISBN` that should work.

Comment: Done. I'm not sure if this is a sufficient edit, so please let me know if there's anything else needed.

Comment: @SwimmingDolphin So, what you want it's that the input that the user makes at the console will have a good format, I mean, without any character? And I don't understand your last `Java Result` sorry.

Comment: Somewhat. The user must enter the designated amount of characters (which is 10). Any lower or higher will result in an error. Any input with letters will output an error with a Java result of 3 (small requirement). I updated the post with all of the incorrect and correct examples.